# Sorting columns in iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I am using java-jasper report and iReport to build the report. I want to make my report sortable by column.

Comment: what is your datasource? I suggest you sort directly from the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do that, one is using ORDER BY in sql query itself another option  is "HTML Template Exporter". It supports column sorting, hide/showing sections (folding), and pop-up windows. It is a utility available in the [JasperShop.](http://www.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-template-exporter-jasperreports)

Answer (score 1):

Coming from definitive guide to iReport book:

Sort and filter options can be set from the Report query dialog box by clicking the buttons labeled Sort options and Filter Expressions.

Comment: This works even if you are filling the dataset from 'JasperFillManager.fillReport' instead of a query.